# Accessing and inserting data into SQL Server database from Windows Service application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have tried inserting data into my database using a Windows Service application but I have failed to achieve the results. The service runs. The connection strings are right but just can't get the data inserted.

I have tried to do my research online... so far no great attempts have been found. Is there anyone with a solution?

Thank you.

```
// this is my service class
public partial class sacc : ServiceBase
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand com;

    string query = string.Empty;

    SqlDataReader reader;

    GlobalConnector gc = new GlobalConnector();
    SerialPort sp;
    string temp;

    public sacc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    }

   public sacc(string[] args)        
   {
       this.CanStop = true;
       this.CanPauseAndContinue=true;
       InitializeComponent();            
       string eventSourceName = "MySource";            
       string logName = "MyNewLog";            

       if (args.Count() > 0)            
       {                
           eventSourceName = args[0];            
       }            

       if (args.Count() > 1)            
       {                
           logName = args[1];           
       }            

       eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();            

       if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(eventSourceName))            
       {               
           System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventSourceName, logName);           
       }           

       eventLog1.Source = eventSourceName;           
       eventLog1.Log = logName;       
    }

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(gc.connnectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();

            sp = new SerialPort(AutodetectArduinoPort(), 9600);

            sp.Open();
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            sp.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceive);

            query = "delete from temperature";

            using (var com = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void datareceive(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int countbt = sp.BytesToRead;

        if (countbt > 3)
        {
            byte[] recbyte = new byte[countbt];

            sp.Read(recbyte, 0, countbt - 1);

            char deg = (char)176;

            temp = recbyte[2].ToString() + " " + deg + " Celcius";

            //  label3.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recbyte,2,1);

        }
    }

    private string AutodetectArduinoPort()
    {
        ManagementScope connectionScope = new ManagementScope();
        SelectQuery serialQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(connectionScope, serialQuery);

        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
            {
                string desc = item["Description"].ToString();
                string deviceId = item["DeviceID"].ToString();

                if (desc.Contains("Arduino"))
                {
                    return deviceId;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            /* Do Nothing */
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And this is my `projectinstaller.cs`:

```
 private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
        serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
    }
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: You need to add more in order for anyone to help you. What happens currently for instance?

Comment: So you have code that is not working but you don't show us anything about this code. We need a crystall ball to guess what's going on there.

Comment: [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) also since we left this at home this morning [The All Knowing](http://www.amazon.com/Amlong-Crystal-Clear-Including-Wooden/dp/B004ZWMA3Y/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438893789&sr=8-1&keywords=crystal+ball) and we can't see the code that you see.. then how the heck do you expect anyone to answer this non question for you..?

Comment: Well clearly you need to alter the watchamecallit and make sure you reference the thingamajig. Then double check the watzadoodle hasn't been corrupted and if so rerun using Fzzzzbbbb. I'm sure you will understand this based on how you write your questions. Seriously though, add your code to give us a chance.

Comment: I am willing to bet if you put a breakpoint on `con.Open();` in your `timer1_Elapsed(...)` event handler, you'd figure out your issue in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Thanks Ragerory, but wat u tryin to mean by breakpoint

Comment: You have got to learn how to [use a debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details required but from past experience its most likely to be a Security Issue!! here is details to solve it

You need to check Windows Service properties and check under what credentials its running.

SQL Server needs to have that user added to access database.

e.g if you use SYSTEM then add SYSTEM to SQL Server roles and give it access to database you want to access.

This should resolve your problem

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sumeet Kumar, Well i guess the work around this issue would give me a solution..but the problem is how i would get to add system to SQL server roles and grant its access.